# C# Database SQL OleDb.OleDbException

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to select items from a database, using SQL in this code

```
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    MessageBox.Show(receivedMessage);
                    connection.Open(); 
                    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT [Username] from [TbLeaderBoard] WHERE [Title] = '[{receivedMessage}]'";

                    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I have this error **"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'"** From the last line "OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();"

receivedMessage = "admin";

any help would be apricated.

Also similar code to this does work in other aspects of the code just not here.

Comment: Why '[{receivedMessage}]'? Is the text in Title '[admin]'?

Comment: And you are vulnerable to SQL Injection. Never pass user input directly to SQL.

Comment: **No value given for one or more required parameters.**, see: [OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: You aren't using parameters here (bad). So the message is triggered by OleDb unable to parse one or more names for columns or table. Check your spelling

Comment: And being a very probable parser error, you should also specify what database system are you using. (Acccess, MySql, Sql Server, Sqlite)?

Answer (score -1):

i wrote this code and connected to sql server and Remove '[' in '{receivedMessage}' ,my code is true

maybe you connect other source or data is dirty

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog= TestDB1; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
string receivedMessage = "";
receivedMessage = "admin";
connection.Open();
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT [Username] from [TbLeaderBoard] WHERE [Title] = '{receivedMessage}'";

OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You can create insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
 create table TbLeaderBoard(Username varchar(100),title varchar(100))
insert into TbLeaderBoard
(Username,title)
select 'aa','admin'
union all  select 'aa','user'
```